# Laravel - Execute console command on the current server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Explain me pls. How to execute commandline commands, from my controller.

for example i want to start icecast server

of course i can use `exec('icecast2 run -c path/to/config.xml')`

is there Laravel way to do this?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/envoy

Comment: @GONG Yeah, saw this already, but i cant get how to call envoy command from my controller

Comment: I don't think there's a "Laravel way" to do this. You can use `exec` or `shell_exec` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `macro` in your `Envoy.blade.php`, read more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/envoy

```
@macro('deploy')
    //your commands here
@endmacro
```

The yo can call it through the Symfony Process (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#usage), like so:

```
$process = new Process("/home/$user/.composer/vendor/bin/envoy run deploy");
$process->setTimeout(3600);
$process->setIdleTimeout(300);
$process->setWorkingDirectory(base_path());
$process->run(function ($type, $buffer)
{
    //print output
});
```

It even better to create some external class for this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class Envoy
{

public function run($task, $live = false)
{
    $result = [];

    $process = new Process('~/.composer/vendor/bin/envoy run '. $task);
    $process->setTimeout(3600);
    $process->setIdleTimeout(300);
    $process->setWorkingDirectory(base_path());
    $process->run(
        function ($type, $buffer) use ($live, &$result) {
            $buffer = str_replace('[127.0.0.1]: ', '', $buffer);

            if ($live) {
                echo $buffer . '</br />';
            }

            $result[] = $buffer;
        }
    );

    return $result;
}
}
```

And call it from controller:

```
public function store(Request $request, Envoy $envoy)
{
    $group = $this->group->create($request->all());

    $result = $envoy->run('<some command>');

    // Do something with $result...
}
```

Credits: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/run-envoy-from-controller